# How to resolve the npm error while creating react project on vs code

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-04T03_43_30_067Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\React> how to resolve this error

i want to full solution to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

Try running your application from Command Prompt/Terminal.
This might be a permission issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try running  the command as root administrator and use `npx`

```
sudo npx create-react-app my-app
```